# T-SQL, OPENROWSET copying tables between databases on the same server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openrowset

I am developping some code that transfers data between SQL servers. In this phase, all my work is on the same server (local, where I am the owner), but I am already trying to implement the OPENROWSET functionnalities that will be used at production time (where  data will be on different servers and where I will have to build queries for the transfers). The following 3 codes are supposed to do the very same thing, but the one making use of OPENROWSET is giving me an error ... Bref, I am stuck! if anyone could help...

3 parts naming: works

```
USE db1
SELECT * INTO dbo.myTable FROM db2.dbo.myTable
```

OPENDATASOURCE: works

```
USE db1
SELECT * INTO dbo.myTable FROM OPENDATASOURCE
    ('SQLOLEDB', 
    'Data Source=127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI'
    ).db2.dbo.myTable
```

OPENROWSET: does not work

```
USE db1
SELECT * INTO dbo.myTable FROM OPENROWSET
    ('SQLOLEDB', 
     'Trusted_Connection=yes;Server=(Local)', 
     'db2.dbo.myTable')
```

Where I am getting the following message:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(null)" returned message "An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections.".
```

Of course I have tried to use the standard properties of my connection string (as with OPENDATASOURCE) but I was also getting the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid authorization specification".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid connection string attribute".
```

Comment: Are you going to be using actual linked servers for prod, or are you going to run OPENROWSET every time you want to do this?

Comment: This point is still unclear, so I'm still considering that we'll be working without linked servers. By the way, I already tested OPENQUERY with success. But I'd still be very happy to understand why I cannot have theis OPENROWSET working as expected!

Comment: Fair enough. I'm on a mobile device but msdn recommends that a linked server be used in such a situation and that OPENROWSET be used for one-off implementations. Are you in a position to make such design recommendations?

Comment: If needed (I mean really needed) It will be more than a recommendation, just an instruction! But I still do not understand why I was unable to make this work!

Comment: If "this" OPENROWSET is not working then look "this" syntax and security are the the likely suspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing: Your `OPENROWSET` statement isn't specifying the server instance.

Try

```
USE db1
SELECT * INTO dbo.myTable FROM OPENROWSET
    ('SQLOLEDB', 
     'Trusted_Connection=yes;Server=127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS', 
     'db2.dbo.myTable')
```